# Bash, append string to file, if it doesn't exist.

Tags: bash

I have a bash function that gets the files in 2 directories and appends them to a file, I also have an `if` statement to check if the filename already exist. If it doesn't exist, write it. But the check doesn't seem to be working, because I can see the filenames written twice.

Here is my function.

```
function getFiles {
     for entry in "$outputDir"/*
     do
        if ! grep -Fxq "$entry" $rlog
         then
            echo ${entry##*/} >> $rlog
        else
             printf "\n filename exists \n"
        fi
     done

     for files in "$dataCopy"/*
     do
        if ! grep -Fxq "$files" $rlog
        then
             echo ${files##*/} >> $rlog
        else
             printf "\n filename exists \n"
        fi
     done
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is failing due to your use of `grep -x` OR exact match.

This is because your `grep` command is checking for `$entry` in log file using:

```
grep -Fxq "$entry" $rlog
```

but you are actually writing `${entry##*/}` into output log using

```
echo ${entry##*/} >> $rlog
```

Comment: That didn't work, I changed `$entry` from the if statement to `${entry##*/}` and that fixed it.

Comment: Yes that should work. `grep -Fq "$entry" $rlog` won't work because `$entry` is much more than `${entry##*/}`.